# Pager:Pass additional arguments in HTML_Ajax.replace func

Tags: php, pear, pager

Sorry for the noob question

I am using a simple mvc model of putting data in datastore and passing the database table name q as a argument from view.

Code:

```
function showUser(str){ 
url = 'getuser.php?q='+ str ; 
HTML_AJAX.replace('txtHint', url);
```

}

I am using following pager mod to display pages. How can I pass additional table name as argument in the filename of the page params?(see the below snippet). So that clicking page links show me the required database set

Code:

```
$pager_params = array( 
'mode'     => 'Sliding', 
'append'   => false,  //don't append the GET parameters to the url 
'path'     => '', 
'fileName' => 'javascript:HTML_AJAX.replace(\'txtHint\',\'getuser.php?pageID=%     d\');',  //Pager replaces "%d" with the page number... 
'perPage'  => 10, //show 10 items per page 
'delta'    => 1, 
'itemData' => $Data 
);
```

Currently clicking the link pageid gives me SQL error since it doesnt pass the table name

Comment: Why don't you set them in the `fileName`?

Comment: ok i did manage to pass the additional arguments in filename param as _italic_ **bold** `\'target\',\'&q=\' + <?php echo $data1 ?> + \'getuser.php?pageID=%d\'` where $data1 is the allready stored in tablename from previous query. and updating the function as _italic_ **bold** `url = 'getuser.php?q='+ str + '&pageID=%d'`. but issue is now its not replacing the div i am getting overwritten seperate query. please help

Comment: I had to change the append param to 'true' as well. clicking on page link i.e

Comment: Please add your solution as answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Converting the comment to an answer:

---

ok i did manage to pass the additional arguments in filename param as

```
 \'target\',\'&q=\' + <?php echo $data1 ?> + \'getuser.php?pageID=%d\'
```

where `$data1` is the already stored in tablename from previous query. and updating the function as

```
url = 'getuser.php?q='+ str + '&pageID=%d'
```

but issue is now its not replacing the div i am getting overwritten separate query. This can be fixed with changing the `append` param to `true` as well.